# How do I get godoc to generate import dependency graphs for my project?

Tags: go, godoc

I have installed go on my Mac; and godoc appears to work, but when using `godoc -http=...` I get nice pages but without a dependency graph.

Comment: Why do you think godoc should do that?

Comment: @Volker I think I may have confused `GoDoc` with `godoc`. The former (the site) generates package graphs, but the latter (command) doesn't appear to.  How do I generate these graphs for myself?

Comment: [oracle](http://godoc.org/code.google.com/p/go.tools/cmd/oracle) could be interesting for you.

Comment: The source code for godoc is open, and looking at it, it looks like it builds the dependency graph by analyzing the code, then outputs an svg string, and renders the graph with dot. see here: https://github.com/golang/gddo/blob/master/gddo-server/graph.go

Comment: So guys, how do you serve the doc with the graph locally?